# Remove all string after a space

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have this variable

c#

```
string text = "val1  val2";
```

javastript

```
var text = "val1  val2"
```

I need a example to remove everything after the space so that the result is 
 `string textModified = "val1";`

Can u help me?

Comment: You are looking for `c#`, `javascript` or both???

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In both the cases, just split on `" "` and take the element on index `0`. The below is for [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
alert(text.split(" ")[0]); // Javascript
```

And this is for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

```
Console.WriteLine(text.Split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: This is the most stress free way to get `0th` element THAN removing all.

Comment: @GonzaloRivera glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

One example would be:

c#

```
string text = "val1  val2";
string textModified = text.Split(' ')[0];
//Another way:
string textModified = text.IndexOf(' ');
var textModified = text.Substring(0, index);
```

Js

```
    var text = "val1  val2";
    var textModified = text.Split(' ')[0];

    // Another way:
    var index = text.indexOf(' ');
    var textModified = text.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: I believe you meant `split(' ')`, else you'd split on every letter.

Comment: I believe you also meant `Split` and not `split`.

Comment: Wait.. I'm lost, was this answer supposed to be for JS or c#?

Comment: @Spokey I wrote both LOL.

Answer (score 1):

here another approach with SubString

```
string text = "val1 val2";
int Space = text.IndexOf(' ');
string textModified = text.Substring(0, Space > 0 ? Space : text.Length);
```

and Linq

```
string text = "val1 val2";
string textModified = new string(text.TakeWhile(x => x != ' ').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting:

```
var word = text.substr(0, (text + " ").indexOf(" "));
```

(Swap to `.Substring` / `.IndexOf` in C#)

---

For fun, C# and JS (ES5) both:

```
var output = ""; var i = 0;
text += " ";
while (text[i] != ' ')
    output += text[i++];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Remove` to remove everything after space. Use `String.IndexOf` to find space in the string.

```
string text = "val1  val2";
string newText = text.Remove(text.IndexOf(' '));
```

You can also check if the string contains a space or not like:

```
if (text.Contains(' '))
{
    string newText = text.Remove(text.IndexOf(' '));
}
```

This will save you from the exception in case of absence of space in the string.

As for JavaScript: you can do:

```
console.log(text.substr(0,text.indexOf(' ')));
```

Should add checking for presence of space as well.

Comment: Can you please give eg. for javascript too ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com, not an expert in javascript but `text.substr(0,text.indexOf(' '));` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to through away data you may need in the future so how about just breaking up the string into components.  Since you know a space is a separator just set space " " as the delimiter for breaking up the line.  The following is an example:

```
string[] read_Items = new string[15];
string text = "val1  val2"
int item_cnt = 0;

// set delimiter for a single space  
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ' };


// Remove and double spaces and replace them with single spaces
 while (test.Contains("  "))
    test = test.Replace("  ", " ");

// Break up line into individual items
foreach (string word in test.Split(delimiters))
{
    read_Items[item_cnt] = word;
    item_cnt++;
    if (item_cnt > 14)
        break;
 }
```

Now you have an array of items you can size this to fit any number of items in a line.  Note: If you needed to have more then one delimiter say you also needed to split on '=', ':'your delimiter definition would be:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '=', ':' };
```

Comment: `string.Split` returns a `string[]`, so why are you iterating that and putting the values into another array whose size might be larger or smaller than the number of split items?  Also instead of replacing double space you can just use the overload of `string.Split` that takes `StringSplitOptions` and pass in `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, that will handle any number of consecutive spaces as one delimiter.